# IIS Manager missing Configuration Editor

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, virtualbox

I'm working on a simple locally hosted webserver for school using virtualbox.
I've stumbled upon a problem. I can't seem to find the Configuration Editor Icon in the IIS Manager.

As a guide I'm using [Testlab Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6815) but I can't seem to find the Icon it's telling me to click.

Anybody know how best to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which OS/Server are you using ?

Configuration Editor is included in [Administration Pack](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/administration-pack) for IIS 7.0.

The functionality of the Administration Pack was integrated into the Windows Server 2008 R2/Windows 7 installation. You don't need to install additional Extension since IIS 7.5

Comment: I had already figured this out but your answer is exactly what I did so I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Administration Pack for IIS 7.0 at the link above appears to be deprecated and no longer available for download.